# Unexpected jquery selector result

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a table with a list of items, check boxes next to each item, and a button to delete checked items.

So I have this selector in jquery to delete the rows of the selected check boxes after coming back from an ajax call to delete the affected items:

```
tr input[name=storePurchaseItemIds\\[\\]][value=" + id + "]
```

I expected it to select all "tr" elements that have an input whose name is storePurchaseItemIds[] and have a value of the id variable.

Instead it seems to have done the opposite: Selected all inputs that are part of a row (when I called remove() on the result it removed the check boxes, leaving the rows in tact).

Clearly there is something I have misunderstood about selectors and am curious why the unexpected result happens.

Comment: That selector is like CSS, saying "select all `input`s with these special attribute values, that are descendants of a `tr`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the descendant selector here, so it selects the input elements, instead you need to select `tr` elements which has `input` elements matching the criteria. So use [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector) or [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has) as given below

```
$("tr:has(input[name=storePurchaseItemIds\\[\\]][value=" + id + "])")
```

or

```
$("tr").has("input[name=storePurchaseItemIds\\[\\]][value=" + id + "]")
```

Comment: Now that I see it I knew that.  Brain fart moment I guess.